# Django view for storing files from request

Tags: django, file-upload, django-file-upload

I'm building a django application that will be operated via desktop application. Key feature for now is sending/storing files. Basically I need a django view with URL on which I can send files with POST and this view will store the files. Currently I have something like this :

```
def upload(request):
    for key, file in request.FILES.items():
        path = settings.MEDIA_URL + '/upload/' + file.name
        dest = open(path.encode('utf-8'), 'wb+')
        if file.multiple_chunks:
            for c in file.chunks():
                dest.write(c)
        else:
            dest.write(file.read())
        dest.close()
        destination = path + 'files_sent.txt'
        file = open(destination, "a")
        file.write("got files \n")
        file.close
```

and urlconf:

```
url(r'^upload/$', upload, ),
```

that supports sending chunked files. But this doesn't work. Is the code correct ? Should I take a different approach, like providing a model with file field and in this function creating a new model instance instead of writing file to disk ?

Comment: If you are sending a normal POST request, with request.FILES populated, why not just use a Django Forms and `FileField` to let it do all the work? This also makes your app flexible in case you ever want to use the form in another way.

Comment: you mean on the receiver side ? post is sent from python app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provides a whole API for receiving and storing files - you should probably read [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/file-uploads/).